# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client Oracle Managed Provider

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-deployment

I developed a MVC 4 application using Oracle database. Everything worked fine until i deployed the application in IIS on the same PC. When I try to login (database operation), I get the following error message.

```
The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

[image]

Same application is working fine on the same PC in Visual Studio's Development Server.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. What is the version of installed Oracle Client and what is the version of ODP.NET (.i.e. Oracle.DataAccess.dll)? They have to match.

Comment: According to your error message you do not use the Oracle Managed Provider. `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` is the unmanaged driver.